# How to mock not implemented Dependency injection?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, rhino-mocks

I want to unit test the following code.right now I'm using NUnit with Rhino Mock.

> Note: All the NUnit test cases should not do any database operation

```
 interface IdbOperation  
 {
      int  insert();
 }

 public class databaseactivity:IdbOperation 
 { 
    public databaseactivity()
    {
      verifyDBConnection(); 
    }

    void verifyDBConnection() 
    { 
      DbManager dbManager=new  DbManager();

      if(dbManager.state()!=True)   
      {
        Throw new DatabaseException();
      }
    }

    public int insert(bo obj)   
    {   
      Serviceclient  serviceClient=new  Serviceclient(); 
      serviceClient.insert(obj);
    }
 }
```

In the above code, i want to write a unit test case for insert method.i tried lot of way but not able to mock.so could please anyone help me for mocking insert method.ASAP

You can suggest me any other mocking framework also.

Comment: Unit testing with mocks is not going to work without dependency injection. Such is life.

Comment: A thousand times this. You need to refactor your code so that you don't have these concrete classes being instantiated in methods. Could not +1 @sq33G comment quick enough.

Comment: Thanks i agree your concerns ,i discussed with client,but they are not ready to change the existing code..thats why i came here to find any alternative route.. Did microsoft moles will help?

Comment: What do you want to test in that method. That insert in ServiceClient was called and received bo obj as parameter?

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
public databaseactivity(IDbManager dbManager = null)
{
  DbManager dbManager = dbManager ?? new DbManager();
  // ...
}
```

If you need to re-create instances (like it seems to be the case with the `ServiceclientFactory`), you need to inject a factory (I would try to avoid this, because it makes things more complicated):

```
public databaseactivity(ServiceclientFactory serviceClientFactory = null, /*...*/)
{
  // ...
  this.serviceClientFactory = serviceClientFactory ?? new DefaultServiceClientFactory();
}

public int insert(bo obj)   
{   
  serviceClient = this.serviceClientFactory.CreateServiceClient(); 
  serviceClient.insert(obj);
}
```

Comment: I wonder how you can benefit from unit tests when the code can't change. Why do you care about existing errors, when you can't fix them? You can't even break anything anymore when you can't change the code.

Comment: can  microsoft moles  will mock above code.without implementing DI?